# Redirecting only the root site to another site IIS

Tags: iis, web

I have a website from which I just need to redirect the main site to another site. For example: My website www.xyz.com should be redirected to www.abc.com ,  but my website sub-sites should not be affected.  Example: www.xyz.xom/forums should be the same link. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should be able to do this within the control panel of whichever web web host you are using. Otherwise, use javascript in your main page (abc.com): `window.location('http://your.url.here', '_self');`.